# pecl install oci8 under php 5.6

Tags: php, ssl, pecl, oci8, php-5.6

I have a vagrant vm with php 5.6 - *homestead* - I am tryingto install oci8 driver for php.

I am behind a corporate SSL proxy, and I cannot succeed in using PECL:

**cert locations**

```
Array
(
    [default_cert_file] => /usr/lib/ssl/cert.pem
    [default_cert_file_env] => SSL_CERT_FILE
    [default_cert_dir] => /usr/lib/ssl/certs
    [default_cert_dir_env] => SSL_CERT_DIR
    [default_private_dir] => /usr/lib/ssl/private
    [default_default_cert_area] => /usr/lib/ssl
    [ini_cafile] => /etc/ssl/certs/acme.pem
    [ini_capath] => /etc/ssl/certs
)
```

*/usr/lib/ssl/cert.pem* => This is the certificate of the SSL proxy, the same one used by cURL, npm, composer and it works great

**php.ini**

```
[curl]

curl.cainfo = /etc/ssl/certs/acme.pem

[openssl]
openssl.cafile = /etc/ssl/certs/acme.pem
openssl.capath = /etc/ssl/certs
```

**pecl config**

```
vagrant@sherwood:/usr/share/php$ sudo pecl config-show
Configuration (channel pecl.php.net):
=====================================
Auto-discover new Channels     auto_discover    <not set>
Default Channel                default_channel  pecl.php.net
HTTP Proxy Server Address      http_proxy       http://usr:pwd@proxy:port/
PEAR server [DEPRECATED]       master_server    pear.php.net
Default Channel Mirror         preferred_mirror pecl.php.net
Remote Configuration File      remote_config    <not set>
PEAR executables directory     bin_dir          /usr/bin
PEAR documentation directory   doc_dir          /usr/share/php/doc
PHP extension directory        ext_dir          /usr/lib/php5/20131226
PEAR directory                 php_dir          /usr/share/php
PEAR Installer cache directory cache_dir        /tmp/pear/cache
PEAR configuration file        cfg_dir          /usr/share/php/cfg
directory
PEAR data directory            data_dir         /usr/share/php/data
PEAR Installer download        download_dir     /build/php5-S4xmO_/php5-5.6.10+dfsg/pear-build-download
directory
PHP CLI/CGI binary             php_bin          /usr/bin/php
php.ini location               php_ini          <not set>
--program-prefix passed to     php_prefix       <not set>
PHP's ./configure
--program-suffix passed to     php_suffix       <not set>
PHP's ./configure
PEAR Installer temp directory  temp_dir         /tmp/pear/temp
PEAR test directory            test_dir         /usr/share/php/test
PEAR www files directory       www_dir          /usr/share/php/htdocs
Cache TimeToLive               cache_ttl        3600
Preferred Package State        preferred_state  stable
Unix file mask                 umask            2
Debug Log Level                verbose          1
PEAR password (for             password         <not set>
maintainers)
Signature Handling Program     sig_bin          /usr/bin/gpg
Signature Key Directory        sig_keydir       /etc/pear/pearkeys
Signature Key Id               sig_keyid        <not set>
Package Signature Type         sig_type         gpg
PEAR username (for             username         <not set>
maintainers)
User Configuration File        Filename         /home/vagrant/.pearrc
System Configuration File      Filename         /etc/pear/pear.conf
```

And each time I run `sudo pecl list-all` I get the following error:

> WARNING: channel "pecl.php.net" has updated its protocols, use "pecl channel-update pecl.php.net" to update
>       Connection to `ssl://proxyURL:proxyPORT' failed:

Note that using pear it works, but I cannot find **oci8** package on it.

I cannot seem to find ANY answer about this on the web, can someone help me ?

Comment: What type of linux are you using?